# Password and Login handerling by PHP [MOTION RPI]

Tags: php, security, authentication, raspberry-pi, motion

For the moment I do a little experiment with motion on the Raspberry Pi so that I can create my own little cheap security system :p.

So I add a password on the stream for my case `sanderpi:8081` and also to the configuration page `sanderpi:8080` so now the user had to insert the password and login to get access.

So I want to create a login page that ask a password and login that is connected with a database and when the combination is correct he get access to the webpage that I created. So for now the user needs to insert also the password and login for the stream but is it possible to handle that automatically by PHP that I say that the username is admin and the password is 1234, So that the user not need to do 2 logins?

[image: Login screen to access the motion stream on raspberry pi]
[image: Config file line from where the password is set]

Comment: It seems like you just want to provide a database-backed user authentication and access control setup? Then you can save the stream authentication values as part of the user account. You have many options for creating your authentication/access control setup. Everything from a lightweight form and simple DB user state management, to using a larger framework.

Comment: I want to pass admin and 1234 bij php just for login in on the stream so that the user don't need to insert that anymore and i don't know how to do that